# Closed or open + proof

Tags: general-topology

Proof if $H = \{ (x,y)\mid 0<x<1, 0<y<1\}$ is closed, open or neither.

So I would strongly suggest that it is open because if you draw it you recognize that the complementary set contains all boundary points that intersect $H$ and $H^c$ and is therefore closed. But now I am struggling with proofing it formally since we have never done that before in class. I would choose some $\epsilon$ and try to show that a ball around it is contained fully in $H$ but I can only show $x>0$ and not that it  $x<1$.

I would appreciate some help or suggestions and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X_0=(x_0,y_0) \in H$, let $r = \frac{1}{2}\cdot \text{min}(x_0,y_0,1-x_0,1-y_0)> 0 \to B(X_0,r) \subset H\to H$ is open.

Comment: r is the radius or?

Comment: @Methamortix: r is "take the distance to the nearest side of the square, and then halve it"; $B(X_0, r)$ is then a circle with centre $(x_0, y_0)$ and radius $r$ - i.e. a ball around the arbitrary point, completely contained in the set.

Answer (score 5):

Note that $H= (0,1) \times (0,1)$, i.e it is the product of $2$ open sets. Thus it is open in the product topology.